# Are Underwater Ruins useful for anything?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been exploring a bunch of oceans, and have found an area with a large number of underwater ruins.  Is there anything useful that can be done with this large area?

- Do drowned spawn more frequently in ruins?  (They seem to be, but that could be observer bias on my part)  [This would mean it would be a good spot for a drowned farm for instance]
- Do any other mobs spawn more frequently in/around ruins?

Note: I have read the Wiki for drowned and ocean ruins, and it doesn't say anything either way.  And yes I"m aware that they contain treasure.  I mean once the ruin has been looted is there anything useful to do with it?

Comment: Well, they have loot chests… I'm pretty sure they don't do anything, but I haven't read the code. It's theoretically possible, because their locations are saved: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/locate

Comment: yeah, it seems that other than the loot chests there's no real documentation about it.
and @FabianRöling it probably pops up in ``/locate`` because it's a structure within the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some of the useful features of underwater ruins:

- They contain loot chests.
- They often contain semi-rare materials like prismarine, sea lanterns, and magma blocks.
- If you're looking for monsters to hunt, ruins usually spawn with a few drowned in them.
- In Bedrock Edition only, you get the "Atlantis?" achievement for finding an underwater ruin.

See also: [Underwater Ruins article on Minecraft Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Underwater_ruins).

Comment: I think this answers part of my question, which I didn't state explicitly.  When I found this large area of underwater ruins, there were *a lot* of drowned swimming around.  But, if they just spawn when the ruins spawn, then there's not much to do with the ruin area once you loot it.  Do the drowned continue to spawn in large numbers (like witches in witch huts?) after looting?

Comment: @John no, they spawn as much as normal after the first time. Unfortunately it doesn't work like witch hut where they continuously respawn after they're killed.

Answer (score 1):

About the most important part is loot chests buried within about 50% of the ruins. They contain buried treasure maps. These maps lead to a place where a chest is buried under a layer of material diggable with a shovel (dirt, sand, gravel). The buried treasure chest, among other loot, contains Heart of the Sea, which is the central component needed for crafting a Conduit - an underwater beacon-like device.

(sometimes - occasionally - the buried treasure chest won't spawn. Also, if you open a chest and see it's empty wait a couple seconds, the game sometimes takes a moment to spawn the actual loot.)

Comment: Generally, I find all the loot chest treasure maps point to the same buried treasure chest.   I've not figured out anyway to get them to point to different buried chests.

Comment: @John: The treasure chests locations are generated completely independently from the maps, and the maps always point to the **nearest** treasure chest (discovered or not). Simply - travel far enough. For the same reason it's about impossible to find maps pointing to two different chests within the same group of ruins.